# Azure Databricks: Failed to extract data which is between two timestamps within those same dates using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

**Data type:**

AAPL_Time: timestamp

AAPL_Close: float

**Raw Data:**

```
AAPL_Time                      AAPL_Close
2015-05-11T08:00:00.000+0000   29.0344
2015-05-11T08:30:00.000+0000   29.0187
2015-05-11T09:00:00.000+0000   29.0346
2015-05-11T09:30:00.000+0000   28.763
2015-05-11T10:00:00.000+0000   28.6768
2015-05-11T10:30:00.000+0000   28.7464
2015-05-12T12:30:00.000+0000   28.7915
2015-05-12T13:00:00.000+0000   28.8763
2015-05-12T13:30:00.000+0000   28.8316
2015-05-12T14:00:00.000+0000   28.8418
2015-05-12T14:30:00.000+0000   28.7703
```

I am trying to extract data by `spark.sql("SELECT AAPL_Time, AAPL_Close FROM aapl_table where AAPL_Time between '%09:30:00%' and '%16:30:00%'")`

**I expect the result should be this:**

```
AAPL_Time                      AAPL_Close
2015-05-11T09:30:00.000+0000   28.763
2015-05-11T10:00:00.000+0000   28.6768
2015-05-11T10:30:00.000+0000   28.7464
2015-05-12T12:30:00.000+0000   28.7915
2015-05-12T13:00:00.000+0000   28.8763
2015-05-12T13:30:00.000+0000   28.8316
2015-05-12T14:00:00.000+0000   28.8418
2015-05-12T14:30:00.000+0000   28.7703
```

**Yet, the final result is this:**

```
Query returned no results
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: AFAIK between does not accept wildcard search. you'll have to provide the timestamps. also, the `AAPL_Time` field looks like a string field.

Comment: @samkart. It is `TimeStamp` data type

Answer (score 0):

```
display(spark.sql("SELECT AAPL_Time, AAPL_Close FROM aapl_table where DATE_FORMAT(AAPL_Time,'HHmm') between '0930' and '1630'"))
```

This one solve the problem.

Source: https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D58Y000094DmAfSAK